# Google Search Console dimension "Country" return only abbreviation

Tags: google-search-console, dimensions

I want to return data from the Google Search Console with using dimension "country". And in the result I see not full name of countries, only three symbols.

How can I return full names of countries? If it not possible, then where I can find corresponding to which country which abbreviation suits?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the public dataset available here https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/bigquery-public-data/country-codes?hl=ar&project=nimble-yen-318015. If you are using excel, you can do a v-lookup and if you are using SQL, you can do a join with the dataset.